# Cannot edit Bitmap on Gingerbread

Tags: android, bitmap, nine-patch

I've got a problem with editing Bitmap loaded from NinePatchDrawable. This is the drawable(part of TabWidget drawable from Sherlock - drawable-mdpi/abs__list_pressed_holo_dark): http://imageshack.us/a/img839/4976/tgt6.png

I want to change every single pixel except black and white ones:

```
    int toColor = Color.Red;
    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId);
    Bitmap bitmap = src.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    for(int x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < bitmap.getHeight(); y++){
            if(pixel not black nor white){
                bitmap.setPixel(x, y, toColor);
            }
        }

    byte[] chunk = src.getNinePatchChunk(); 
    return new NinePatchDrawable(res, bitmap, chunk, new Rect(), null);
```

So.. this code works great on Galaxy S2(Jelly Bean), but doesn't work on Galaxy Ace 2(Gingerbread). The new drawable simple doesn't change... what is the problem?

**EDIT:**

The code above works with another Sherlock NinePatchDrawable - abs__ab_transparent_light_holo(http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/7039/otb9.png )..., but doesn't work with first one. I repeat: this just happens on Gingerbread

Comment: The bitmap is probably immutable, you need to make it mutable, take a look at http://sudarnimalan.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/android-convert-immutable-bitmap-into.html

Comment: I copied it first to make it mutable